# jquery each function not getting executed on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery

Why .each is not functioning on dynamically created buttons.

```
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="clickBut">Click</button>
```

js:

```
$("#clickBut").on("click", function(){
console.log("b clicked");
$("#content").append("<div class='buttnContent'><button class='db'>dyn but</button></div><div class='buttnContent'><button class='db'>dyn but</button></div>");
});

$("#content").find(".db").each(function(i,v){
$(this).on("click",function(){
    console.log("dyn but: "+i);
  });
 });
```

when I am clicking on dynamic buttons, nothing is happening.But if i remove each function and clicking then click function is getting executed.
i want value of i to be displayed.Please share your inputs

Comment: [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) , `$("#content").on("click",'.db',function(){
    console.log("dyn but: " + $("#content db").index(this));
  });`

Comment: @PranavCBalan. oh sorry. I didnt see the later part of code an dcommented.. i hav edited. Thanks

Comment: `$("#content .db").index(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for listen to the click event of  dynamically added element. Inside handler use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index) method to get the index of the button.

```
$("#content").on("click",'.db',function(){
  console.log("dyn but: " + $("#content .db").index(this)); 
})
```

```js
$("#clickBut").on("click", function() {
  console.log("b clicked");
  $("#content").append("<div class='buttnContent'><button class='db'>dyn but</button></div><div class='buttnContent'><button class='db'>dyn but</button></div>");
});

$("#content").on("click", '.db', function() {
  console.log("dyn but: " + $("#content .db").index(this));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="clickBut">Click</button>
js:
```